# Trying to create Db doc from sql developer and it successfully works but when i click on index.html no file found

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-dictionary

I am trying to extract a data dictonary from the sql developer.I made sure that i was connect to the database and i am able to write queries and get output. Then i go to generate a db doc it shows successfull and then when i go to the folder and open index.html it says file not found when i try to check the table.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug with the DB Doc feature where the index page is generated but none of the individual pages are being generated. This is fixed for our next update.

Comment: Should i just wait for the update?Could you please guide me if there is another way to create a data dictionary from sql developer.

Comment: Use the data modeler as a workaround, unless you have an older version sitting around

Comment: The version 19.1 don't have this bug. I think this bug is there since version 19.2. The last version is 19.4 from December 2020, but in the bugs doc https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-bugsfixed-194-5908847.html there is no mention to it. 
Now, 5 months have been passed from the last version and the bug still remains. How is this even possible? Oracle please...

Comment: we didn't release version 20.1 b/c of the corona virus pandemic...the fix will be avail in version 20.2, early Summer